# Cloning a repository with tortoise git fails

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I right click on empty folder and select `Git Clone...`, put in the url: `https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=tree` (is that what I'm supposed to put ?) uncheck the Putty key, and get this:

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/incubator-cordova-android" "C:\work\PhoneGapSrc\incubator-cordova-android"

Cloning into 'C:\work\PhoneGapSrc\incubator-cordova-android'...
fatal: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/incubator-cordova-android/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is wrong, it is https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-cordova-android.git